# How can we open a file present on remote machine from local machine using java?

Tags: java, tomcat, server

In a case, a project is running with tomcat server on one machine with a functionality to create a text file on a button click on it's local drive(Example, C:\Project\Sample.txt).

Other users can connect to this server and have the same view but when this remote user clicks on button then the file is getting created on local path of the machine where server is running,

so the question is, can we open or download a file on remote machine(Example, in remote machine's local drive) for viewing when remote user clicks the same button ?

Example,

Server is running with following URL:

http://localhost:8068/panel.jsp

panels.jsp have a button to create a text file. On clicking this button, a text file will be created at the local drive and opened.

Client is running with following URL,

http://192.168.1.2:8068/panel.jsp

Now, when a client clicks on button, i want to create the text file on Client's local drive (instead of server machine's local drive) and open it.

FYI : localhost = 192.168.1.2

Comment: Please be a bit more precise on your actual goal. E.g. post a diagram or something on what you want to do at what time with what user-interaction

Comment: @Benni i will edit my question, to be precise.

Comment: You can't, unless the local machine can present a filename for the remote file that will work with the `File,` `FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream`, `RandomAccessFile`, or `FileChannel` classes as appropriate. You certainly can't use an HTTP URL as a Java filename.

Comment: Since `panel.jsp` is running on server, file will always be created on server's local drive.  You cannot create a file on client's (browser) drive as it is not permitted in JavaScript.  Can you not create a file on server and download it to client?

Comment: @WandMaker Will you please guide me with some sample code to download file at client side for viewing ?

Comment: @MaximusDecimusMeridius You can google "Download file using Java JSP"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:
http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/servlet-code-to-download-text-file-from-website-java/

Basically, you need the file to be returned from a servlet (or some technology on top of it, eg spring restful support). Make sure you servlet:

1) sets the 'Contenty-Type' header (text/plain for a plain text file, application/vnd.ms-excel for an excel report etc)

2) sets a "Content-Disposition" header: this would cause the browser to properly download to a file (with a meaningful file name of your choice), and not just render it inside the browser window...
Obviously the browser will have to present the user with a 'file download' popup , asking his permission (understandable security issue)

3) then you just write your file content into the response stream or writer.